# display name of month based on number in python django month number store in database like 1,2,3......12

Tags: python, django, django-templates

{{ dt.month }} 
Had try this but work only when we have full date

{{ dt.add_date|date:"F" }}   //get date from db like "2020-03-0718:17:02.300948+05:30" **this is working**

{{ dt.month|date:"M" }}      //get only number from db like 03 **this is not work**

Comment: That makes sense, since `.month` is *not* a datetime object, hence you can not format it like that.

Comment: What is `dt` here? Can you share the model?